# Animation occurs only for first time

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

On CLICKING on view `orhu` i am animatinng ulayout from bottom to top and on clicking on `backgroundview` i am making it invisible by animating top to bottom.But the issue is that both animation occurs only for first time i click on `orbhu`.Then no animation occurs and view just become visible and invisible without animation unless i reopen the activity.Why is this and how can i resolve this?

slide_down

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

slide_up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

Code

```
slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
        R.anim.slide_down);
slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
        R.anim.slide_up);
orbhu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ulayout.setAnimation(slideUp);
        ulayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        backgroundview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
backgroundview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ulayout.setAnimation(slideDown);
        backgroundview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ulayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try View.Invisible instead of View.Gone.

Comment: @Hari_krish4 same issue wid tht also

Comment: Have you tried startAnimation instead of setAnimation

Comment: @Hari_krish4 that solved my issue..can you please post it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code instead

```
slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
        R.anim.slide_down);
slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
        R.anim.slide_up);
orbhu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ulayout.startAnimation(slideUp);
        ulayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        backgroundview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
backgroundview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ulayout.startAnimation(slideDown);
        backgroundview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ulayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```